# How to split into BTC and BTG

Tags: blockchain.info, blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

I have bitcoin in blockchain.info (where i control the private keys) before 25 Oct.

Which exchange/wallet can i use to split the bitcoin into BTC and BTG so that i can sell them separately before 1 Nov 2017?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the snapshot, the coins which you controlled in your wallet would exist in both the original BTC blockchain, and the newly split BTG blockchain.

You can redeem these BTG coins for BTC (or another Cryptocurrency) via an exchange which supports these tokens (eg Bitfinex, Yobit,  etc) once the BTG blockchain is being publicly mined, and transactions can begin.

Selling before this time would have to be done via a futures contract, although I do not believe there are any major platforms trading BTG futures at this time.

Comment: I don't plan to sell BTG yet. But I need to sell my BTC before 1 Nov (need cash urgently), so how could I do that while keeping my BTG? If i send BTC to Bitfinex etc, would it automatically split it into BTC and BTG? If not how can i instruct it to?

Comment: BTC can be sold through any normal exchange right now, without affecting the BTG. Just send the BTC to the exchange as normal, the transaction will not appear on the BTG chain as it occurred after the snapshot date.

Comment: So I simply have to retain my private keys, so even if blockchain.info show my BTC balance as 0, i'd still have my BTG with these private keys? So my BTG are tagged to my private keys and as long as I don't touch them, blockchain will not remove/alter them?
Then in the future I can deposit into a BTG wallet using these private keys?

Comment: Correct. If blockchain.info does not support BTG you will have to export the keys to a wallet which supports sending transactions on the BTG network.